# A question regarding flux of a vector field $\overrightarrow{F} $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, multiple-integral

So I have a surface:
$$ \text{S} : z=x^2+(y-R)^2$$

Vector field is defined by:

$$\overrightarrow{F}(x, y, z) = (y, - x, z(x^2+y^2))$$

I have to calculate flux in $~2~$ different scenarios.

**First** one is:

Through a part of the surface $S$ that has an additional condition: $x^2+y^2 \leq R^2$

So with this one I think, I should find the appropriate parametrization and just use the formula for surface integral:

$$\iint_{S} \overrightarrow{F} dP=\iint_{D} \overrightarrow{F}(\overrightarrow{r} (u, v) *(\overrightarrow{r_u} × \overrightarrow{r_v}) dudv$$

So I need help getting the correct parametrization  to use, and the necessary bounds.

My idea is to manipulate the cylindrical coordinates into something that would work for my case.
$$x=r\cos\phi$$
$$y=r\sin\phi$$
$$z=z$$
Would using $z=x^2+(y-R)^2$ and inserting x, y get me the correct parametrization?
and just use $ r\leq|R|$ and $\phi\in[0,2\pi] $ good enough, or am I doing something wrong?

**Second** one is through $\delta G$ where $~G~$ is bounded by  $S$ from above and $x^2+y^2=R^2  , z=0  $

So with this one I think of using Divergence theorem(Gauss theorem if you know it by this name) :

$$\iint_{\delta G} \overrightarrow{F} dP=\iiint_{G} div \overrightarrow{F} dV$$

so with this one I thought of using the cylindrical coordinates:

$$x=r\cos\phi$$
$$y=r\sin\phi$$
$$z=z$$
$$J=r$$

So i used the surfaces given to get:

$r\in [0,R] , z\in [0, r^2-2\sin\phi + R^2] $

I presume that $[0,2\pi] $ since there is no special conditions on it. Is this part okay, the way I got the bounds.

So any help would be appreciated.

I hope I did not put too many details in one question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first integral your approach is spot-on. But I suggest first using the parametrization 
$$\begin{align}
& x = x \\
& y = y \\
& z = x^2 + (y-R)^2 \\
\end{align} $$
because without calculation you can always use that 
$$r_x \times r_y = (-f_x,-f_y,1)$$
After you take the dot product, $\mathbf{\text{then}}$ convert the scalar double integral into polar coordinates. This method saves a lot of time and heartache from the use of potential obscure trig identities.

Your second part looks alright, but your notation is extremely unfamiliar to me, so I have a few questions.

When you put (a) and (b) next to your surfaces, are they denoting parts (a) and (b) of a question or just two surfaces to bound the region with?

And when you go into cylindrical coordinates, what is J?

Lastly, your $z$ upper bound should be $r^2 - 2Rr\sin \phi +R^2$

Comment: i just used the a) amd b) to show where i got bounds

Comment: what about the answer to my other question?

Comment: oh you mean $J$, that is the Jacobi determinant, we use this notation, since it's divergence theorem, it is the regular triple integral, so Jacobi comes  in use

Comment: Oh ok, the way you had it formatted I was concerned it was another variable. Then your second approach works too. Try my suggestion for the first question and you'll have the best method for both problems.